# How to create a dynamic layout from json

Tags: android

I have layout made from XML and a JSON from which this layout is to be inflated.

The issue is that I have to create a dynamic class extending `linearlayout` and create this layout and inflate it.

The image below is the same layout inflated two times on the basis of this JSON:-

```
{
"data": {
    "layouts": [
        {
            "text": "Loss Date",
            "fromdate": "20-12-2013",
            "todate": "22-12-2014"
        },
        {
            "text": "Loss Date",
            "fromdate": "20-12-2013",
            "todate": "22-12-2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I have done it using listview.

My question is can I create it by extending `linearlayout` and create it and use it in a `listview`/`scrollview`?
Here is the XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/five"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_background" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/datefiltercheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox_filter"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/thirty"
        android:text="Loss Date"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rightDrawerTitleText"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fromdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_todo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="From: 20-12-2014"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_todo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="To: 20-12-2014"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/five"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_background" />
```

[image]

Comment: do you know about **custom adapter** for listview?

Comment: Yes i know. I need to create it like a separate component sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this. And after creation invoke setData method with parsed Json

```
class MyLayout extends LinearLayout{
            public MyLayout(Context context) {
                super(context);
                setOrientation(VERTICAL);
                setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }

            private View createItem(JSONObject data) {
                View v = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
                try {
                    ((CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.datefiltercheckbox)).setText(data.getString("text"));
                    // Other views 
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // or you can create item's layout manually here without using inflater and xml

                return v;

            }

            public void setData(JSONArray array){
                for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                    try {
                        addView(createItem( array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```